# The view comments.views.comment_create_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I'm returning httpresponse object, why am I still getting this error?can someone spot false in my code?
I just don't understand this, I have set my url right and the error is saying it's from this view. What am I doing wrong?

```
def comment_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated():
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
        post_id = request.POST.get("post_id")
        origin_path = request.POST.get("origin_path")
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        except:
            post = None

        parent_comment = None
        if parent_id is not None:
            try:
                parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
            except:
                parent_comment = None

            if parent_comment is not None and parent_comment.post is not None:
                post = parent_comment.post

        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment_text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            if parent_comment is not None:
                # parent comments exists
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user), 
                    path=parent_comment.get_origin, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post,
                    parent=parent_comment
                    )
                return HttpResponseRedirect(parent_comment.get_absolute_url())
            else:
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user), 
                    path=origin_path, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post
                    )
                return HttpResponseRedirect(new_comment.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(origin_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of the code paths result into `HttpResponse` being returned. For example, if the method is not `POST` or the user is not authenticated, the view returns nothing (`None`).